javascript draggable video muted bug
I use Draggable in JavaScript, and even though I used "muted", if the order of the list changes, the video makes sound and plays the audio as many times as the order changes, and even if I delete the video, the audio continues..................
Even if the order of the list changes, I hope the mute property is maintained
<video
    v-if="element.photos.length"
    ghost-class="thing"
    muted
    autoplay
    loop
    style="
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         object-fit: cover;
         background-color: black;
         border-radius: 8px;
    "
>
    <source :src="element.photos[0].photo" type="video/mp4"/>
    현재 브라우저에서 지원되지 않는 형식입니다.
</video>


Please post the generated HTML and not the template in order to create a [mre]
